# Matching strings don't trigger condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to do a very simple stock counting app, and display dynamically the stocks for each item. When I try to pair the button with its item, it doesn't work, even though the 2 strings are actually a match.

Here is the faulty function:

```
socket.on('Stock init', (data) => {
    items = data.items;
    displayStock(items);
});

function displayStock(items) {
    fridgeItem.forEach((fridgeItem) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var databaseProduct = items[i].name;
            var databaseQuantity = items[i].chilled.toString();
            console.log(fridgeItem.textContent, databaseProduct);
        }
        if (fridgeItem.textContent === databaseProduct) {
            fridgeItem.textContent = databaseProduct + '  ' + databaseQuantity;
        } else {
            console.log('err');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer might be stupid but I can't see it at the moment. Thanks

Comment: What's `fridgeItem`? Is this correct: `fridgeItem.forEach((fridgeItem) => {})`?

Comment: Use the javascript debugging in your browser. Set a break points and examine the values and how the if block comparison is working. It should reveal the problem.

Comment: to debug this, i would usually console.log the content like this console.log(`"${fridgeItem.textContent}", "${databaseProduct}"` ... this will help you see if there is an extra space here or there causing it to be different ... you can also just try adding .trim() and .toLowerCase() for both

Comment: First of all thank you guys for taking the time to answer.
After using asawyer's method I found out there WAS a space in the html.. Thanks a lot my problem is solved